# Debugging order of RewriteRules

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I've got a set of RewriteRules which are working fine on a WordPress site with the exception of paginated content.  I'm trying to add in a rule for the pagination but it's not working, leading me to think it's either the execution order that's the problem or that the page I'm rewriting to is incorrect.

Can anyone point me in the right direction to a solution?

**The site currently works as follows:**

http://domain.com <-- Homepage

http://domain.com/blog/ <-- Blog landing page, displaying WP loop of x blog posts

http://domain.com/example-blog-post <-- Blog post

**Background info**

Previously WordPress was installed into a "blog" sub directory, this was then moved out to the domain root hence the other rules.  I've noted my addition on line #9 below:

```
## Moved blog landing page to a subdir
RewriteRule ^blog/(.+)$ /$1 [R=301,L] 

## Redirect legacy urls to domain root
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^blog/? [NC]
RewriteRule ^blog/(.*)$ http://www.domain.com/$1 [R=301,L]

#### My addition ####
RewriteRule ^blog/page/$ /blog/?paged=$1 [L]

# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

Comment: I should add, I've been trying to debug the rewrite rules using http://martinmelin.se/rewrite-rule-tester/ but not having any luck in identifying where I'm going wrong.

Comment: If it were me I would remove all up to # Begin Wordpress, and use the rewrite filters provided by wordpress to modify the rules... http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Rewrite

Comment: @jsuna Thanks for the suggestion, but how would that work with a need to have legacy pages redirected to their new URL?  That's the reason for the condition matching and redirect rule.  If I can get by with just the WP filters that would be my preference too.